# String-array onclick not showing title

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having a little trouble with my string-array in android. The onClick works fine but it doesn't show the title of the clicked item in the new activity. And when I say title, I mean in the toolbar.

```
<string-array name="states">
    <item>Alabama</item>
    <item>Alaska</item>
    <item>Arizona</item>
    <item>California</item>
    <item>Colorado</item>
    <item>Connecticut</item>
</string-array>
```

Here is my code for the fragment it is in

```
public class FragmentState extends Fragment {

    private ListView catagoryList;
    private View root;
    private TreeAdapter adapter;

    public FragmentState() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scholar, container, false);

        catagoryList = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new TreeAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_catagory, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories));


        catagoryList.setAdapter(adapter);

        catagoryList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FragmentState.this.getActivity(), StateView.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return root;

    }

}
```

In my activity

```
public class StateView extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView reship;
    BulletinAdapter ship;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scholar_view);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ptoolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        listTitle();
    }

    private void listTitle() {
        String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);
        int p = 0;
        setTitle(list[p]);
    }
}
```

The method above works but the title only shows the first item clicked. I tried using Intents but it would not display the title either. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the position from `FragmentState`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FragmentState.this.getActivity(), StateView.class);
intent.putExtra("STATE_POSITION", position);
startActivity(intent);
```

And, retrieve it in `State` activity and pass it to `listTitle()`

```
public class StateView extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView reship;
    BulletinAdapter ship;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scholar_view);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int statePosition = intent.getIntExtra("STATE_POSITION", 0); // Here 0 is default value in case `STATE_POSITION` was not sent via intent

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ptoolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        listTitle(statePosition);
    }

    private void listTitle(int statePosition) {
        String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);
        setTitle(list[statePosition]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are using only first index value:

```
  int p = 0;
  setTitle(list[p]);
```

Comment: I know. It is just an example. If I don't have that index, the title shows nothing.

Comment: You'll need to indicate to the fragment which state you want to display from the main activity so you know which one in your list to select.  You can also pass the state name directly instead of using the list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change the string resource array name for the adapter

```
adapter = new TreeAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_catagory, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.states));
```

as you have the array name as states not categories

Second pass the clicked position in bundle before starting 2nd activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FragmentState.this.getActivity(), StateView.class);
intent.putExtras("position",position);                
startActivity(intent);
```

Third in the second activity read this bundle value and assign it to a variable

```
int selectedPosition=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position",0);
```

modify your list title method

```
private void listTitle() {
        String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.states);

        setTitle(list[selectedPosition]);
    }
```